# Removing Title Bar on Android

Tags: android

I've been having a very hard time trying to get rid of the Title Bar on the application I'm developing. I'm using Android Studio.

I've tried almost all the methods that have been listed on various places on the net..

```
super.onCreate()...
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // also used it without the "this"
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
this.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name_here);
```

in the .java file

also tried a couple of other methods in the .java file

I've tried changing the codes in the manifest file  as well using

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

even by changing the theme under the Application tag..

I've tried changing the style tag in the styles.xml to something like

```
<style name="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

but all of these have failed. The app has CRASHED in all of the above instances. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: please post the logcat..

Comment: Why does it crash? Are you using an options menu or calling `getSupportActionbar()`?

Comment: I think you should share your MainActivity.java and your style.xml

Comment: without knowing what the crash is. All you need is `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` in the manifest and nothing else. Delete everything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this before your setContentView(..)

```
Window window = getWindow();
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 20)
    window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_white));
```

or if your ok with it. `@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar` though i prefer not using this.

or if youre using appCompat libs

```
1.Go to your manifest.xml file.

2.Find the activity tag for which you want to hide your ActionBar and then add,

android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"

<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are extending either actionbaractivity or appcompatactivity .Instead of them simply extend Activity and then use
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);